# How to give programatically constraint first view width constraint value equal to second view leading space and so on...?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Below code i have multiple view divide all view equal width and also divide all view with equal width successfully but not leading space increase based on previous view.Please solve this issue.customView is my superview.

```
for i in 0..<countNoOfViews{
            var customView1:UIView!
            customView1 = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
            customView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            customView.addSubview(customView1)


            let widthConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView1, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: customView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1/CGFloat(countNoOfViews), constant: 0)

            let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: customView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)


            let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: customView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView1, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,toItem: customView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            let trailingConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView1, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: customView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier:1.0, constant: 0)

            if i == 0{
                customView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                customView.addConstraints([topConstraint,bottomConstraint,leadingConstraint,widthConstraint1])
            }else if i == 1{
                customView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                 customView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint,widthConstraint1])
            }else if i == 2{
                customView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
                customView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint,trailingConstraint2])
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would you increase the leading space when you want to divide the space? Just say that `previous.Trailing` should equal `next.Leading`? Then  your views will align next to each other.

Comment: but i have multiple view create dynamically so how to give previous trailing.Any way to store width constraint value in one variable ?

Comment: Save the last view in an optional variable outside of your for loop, set the width and the spacing to reference that variable, and set the variable at the end of your loop.

Comment: i have multiple view also increase varible which customly store width constraints value.can you explain in code please.

Comment: What about a horizontal stack view?